# Control characters in Terminal and an international keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, internationalization

I have a Linux server with services running inside `systemd` containers. To access the shell inside a container, I can use the command `machinectl login <container>`. That command will give me the container's login prompt and this message:

`Connected to container <name>. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.`

After I'm done and type `exit` or `logout`, I'm returned to the container's login prompt. In order to get back to the host's shell, I need to send the control character `^]` (three times within one second).

I'm using an international (Finnish) keyboard and instead of having its own dedicated key, the `]` character is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. But when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, it's not recognized as the control character `^]` and I'm stuck at the login prompt.

How can I send a proper `^]` control character with an international keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more direct solution, but here's the one I found.

If you go to
<kbd>Terminal</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences...</kbd> → <kbd>Profiles</kbd> → the profile you're using → <kbd>Keyboard</kbd>
you'll get a list of mappings between function keys and special keystrokes.

[image: Terminal Preferences]

We want to add the `^]` to this list, so click on <kbd>+</kbd>, and choose the key, and optionally modifier, you would like use. (I went with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, and since <kbd>F12</kbd> is also the key for volume up, what I actually need to press is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.)

In the text field, we need to enter the correct control character, but the thing is, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> is not recognized here either. The solution is to directly paste in the correct octal code, which happens to be `\035` (you can copy&paste it from here).

[image: Keyboard Mapping]

Now pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> sends the proper `^]` control character, and I can get back to the host's shell.